# Refining understanding of typescript module resolution and configuration in a monorepo

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vuejs3, monorepo

I have a monorepo (npm workspaces) with typescript 4.7 installed in all my packages.
The repo:

```
root
  apps
    nestjs
      tsconfig.json
    cloud_functions
      tsconfig.json
    frontend (vue3)
      tsconfig.json
  packages
    types
      tsconfig.json
      package.json
    config
      tsconfig.json
      package.json
```

The use case is simple, I want to import constants from the *config* package and types from the *types* one.

The imports of types work fine but the imports of constants are causing me a lot of grief.

*All* my 3 consumers `tsconfig.json` files already have this:

```json
{
  "extends": "@app/tsconfig/tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@app/types": ["../../packages/types"],
      "@app/config": ["../../packages/config"]
    }
    //... other options

  },
  
  "references": [
    { "path": "../../packages/types/tsconfig.json" },
    {
      "path": "../../packages/config/tsconfig.json"
    }
   //... other options
  ]
}
```

NestJS and Cloud Functions are by default CommonJS friendly, i.e:

```json
 "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
   // ... stuff
}
```

When Vue 3 is EsNext friendly:

```json
 "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
   // ... stuff
}
```

Vue 3 default tsconfig comes out of the box with the `"esModuleInterop": true` flag set.

Changing the module value to `ESNext` for NestJS breaks things, so I need to stick to CommonJS.

At this stage, my understanding of the situation is that the "references" set in the consumers help the compiler resolve the dependencies without having to import them as dependencies or devDependencies, and do a fine job at doing that for *types*.

However, the constants (config), i.e, are javascript code, and therefore need extra love to be consumed seamlessly by consumers who have different expectations, namely the CommonJS vs ES6 module dilemma.

My `config/tsconfig.json` is currently defined like so:

```json
{
  "extends": "@app/tsconfig/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "target": "es6",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "types": ["node"]
  },
  "include": ["./index.ts", "./src/**/*.ts"],
  "display": "Config"
}
```

And its package.json like so:

```json
{
  "name": "@app/config",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -b"
  },
  "exports": "./index.js",
  "types": "index.d.ts",
  "private": true
}
```

My expectation was that by exporting to a `commonjs` module format, Vue, with the `esModuleInterop": true` would be able to happily import the config constants. But instead it is giving me this error:

```
/packages/config/index.js' does not provide an export named 'CASL_SUBJECT_ACCOUNT'
```

And clearly, it is not because what I have instead is this:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "CASL_SUBJECT_ACCOUNT", { enumerable: true, get: function () { return casl_1.CASL_SUBJECT_ACCOUNT; } });
```

I have tried also to not export .js files at all (i.e `emitDeclarationOnly: true`) and rely on each consumer to compile the files to its needs but that only created different issues.

So my questions at this stage are:

- can I actually rely on "references" to not have to import packages as dependencies
- do I actually have to generate javascript files in my config package?
- do I need to export my constants as `.cjs`, `.mjs` files to please the consumers OR can I rely on some baked in config options from typescript (e.g `esModuleInterop`)
- What changes can I bring to the config above to fix the existing issues?

Thanks,